# How can i edit the HTML of MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I want to change the HTML structure of MediaWiki and i have no clue which files are responsible for it.

I would be very thankful, if someone could tell me which files are resposible for building the Mediawiki HTML structure.

Answer (score 1):

What you mean by Mediawiki HTML structure is essentially the active skin structure rather than Mediawiki itself. If you want to change look and feed of Mediawiki you need to either alter existing skin (which is [Vector](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:Vector) by default) or build your own skin. Easiest would be to start from these two guides [Manual:Skinning_Part_1](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skinning_Part_2) , [Manual:Skinning_Part_2](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Skinning_Part_2) .

Answer (score 0):

MediaWiki uses PHP to process and display data stored in a MYSQL database. Check the source mirror at Github https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki

There's probably an easier way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah, i can tell that it's displayed via PHP but there are too many PHP files there. I'm looking at them and looking and i see nothing that could render the view.